# Hide outliers in plotly boxplot with px.box in python

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot, outliers

I have the following boxplot in plotly for my streamlit application: `

```
fig = px.box(df, x=x_column, y=y_column, color=x_column)    
st.plotly_chart(fig,use_container_width=True)
```

I have not found a working solution to hide the outliers in my boxplot.

The boxplot:

[image]

The desired boxplot:

[image]

Anyone who knows how I can achieve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Remove it from your data

Comment: @drum how can plotly make a boxplot with the correct quartiles if outliers aren't included in your data?

Comment: @DerekO Exactly, I don't want to remove them from my dataframe but just want to zoom in on the boxplot visualisation since my outliers have extreme

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`points=False`](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.box.html)   to remove outliers:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.box(df, y="total_bill", points=False)
fig.show()
```

**With outliers:**

[image]

**After removing outliers:**
[image]

Comment: This just removes the points visualisation and changes it into a longer whisker. The boxplot still has the same y-ax with the outliers on it. It is something different than what I want to achieve. As you can see in my example, I would like to 'zoom in' on the boxplot by only showing the y-ax up to the value of the IQ's. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: You want to keep outliers but zoom in the area of IQ's?

Comment: @Hamzah when you use the argument `points=False`, then according the documentation, "no sample points are shown and the whiskers extend to the full range of the sample". what @olive wants is for the whiskers to remain in their default position of the `box edges ± 1.5*IQR`

Comment: @DerekO, yes, thanks for clarification, I think I try to answer his question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73978574/16733101